# Make button behave like checkbox in React

Tags: html, reactjs, button, checkbox

I want to make a button behave like a checkbox in React, so the button that has been selected/clicked can return its value again or can be unselected again. But I haven't found a way.

Here's my code

```
  const handleSelectedValue = (reason: any) => {
    setSelectedValues(item => [...item, reason]);
  };
  

  // if value selected then change style
  const checkId = (id: number) => {
    return selectedValues.map(item => item.id).includes(id);
  };

 // inside jsx
 {reasons.map(item => {
      return (
        <button
           key={item.id}
           className={`mr-2 mb-2 text-xs border-2 rounded-full font-semibold border-card-primary px-3 sm:px-5 py-2 ${checkId(item.id) ? 'text-white bg-base-primary opacity-75 border-none' : 'text-base-secondary'}`}
           onClick={() => handleSelectedValue(item)}
         >
            {item.reason}
         </button>
     );
 })}
```

This code works, but the selected value cannot be unselect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the existence of reason in the array. If it exists remove it else add it to list. You always add it.

```
const handleSelectedValue = (values) => {
  setSelectedValues((item) => {
    let idx = item.findIndex((itm) => itm.id === values.id);
    if (idx !== -1) {
      return item.filter(itm => itm.id !== values.id)
    } else {
      return [...item, values];
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Okay thank you, I have try it, but if I have selected one button, then, if I click it again, the button not unselected

Comment: here's the code and the demo in the codesandbox that I made
https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-star-ul7wt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Nevermind, i changed it like this ```[...item.splice(item.findIndex(itm => itm === reason), 0)]``` and it works

Comment: sorry to ask again, now if more than one button has been selected, and one button is unselected then all buttons are also unselected, is there any way to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer, I made some mistakes and they solved. check it and accept it if it is correct. @muhfaridzia